# Displaying Custom Taxonomy Children in Dropdown

Tags: taxonomy, children

I have a question I hope you can help me with. I have a custom taxonomy called locations and on the first level I have the areas (Asia, Europe, etc) and under each area I have countries (England, South Africa). What I would like to do it display a dropdown menu of all the children of that particular parent similar to what was done here, http://wordpress.org/support/topic/terms-of-custom-taxonomy-in-a-dropdown-menu . However, I want the dropdown to only display the children of the parent page I am currently on, not all the terms. So if I am on North America I want it to show the United States and Mexico and if I am on the Europe parent page I want it to show England.

Does that make sense?

Nick

Comment: Sweetness that works great one last question. When I am on the parent page it works great but when I am on the child page it displays an empty list is there any way when on a child page it can display all the children of its parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `get_query_var( 'term' )` to get the current term and `get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ) to get the current taxonomy, then all that is left is to use [wp_dropdown_categories()][1] function with`child_of`parameter and`taxonomy` parameter,
so something like this:

```
//first get the current term
 $current_term = get_term_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'term' ), get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ) );
//then set the args for wp_dropdown_categories
 $args = array(
    'child_of' => $current_term->term_id,
    'taxonomy' => $current_term->taxonomy,
    ); 
 wp_dropdown_categories( $args );
```

Done!